# Skip a record in LoadFunc.getNext()

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm extending the LoadFunc. In the getNext function I'd like to skip returning a tuple under certain conditions - this way I could only load a sample of the data file. I tried returning null for the rows I don't want to return but the problem is that the method terminates after the first null Tuple is returned.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Should I do it in a different method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Assuming you mean [LoadFunc](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.0/api/org/apache/pig/LoadFunc.html) in Pig ... )

I would suggest writing a new method that does what you want simply to not break the original documented use of the `getNext()` method.

You should look at the source for the Pig classes that extend `LoadFunc` and see how they implement `getNext()`. For example: [TextLoader](http://search-hadoop.com/c/Pig:/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/TextLoader.java%7C%7C+%2522local+file%2522+%2522String+msg%2522)

From there it should be fairly trivial to do what you're trying to do.

**Edit to try and offer a little more detailed help:**

(This is using the TextReader as an example)

The `getNext()` method is reading from a `RecordReader`. It does this by calling `RecordReader.nextKeyValue()` to advance to the next record. You check to see if that's true (meaning it read a record) and if it is, you call `RecordReader.getCurrentValue()` to retrieve the value.

Lets say you only wanted every fifth one as a sample in `getNext()`:

```
int count = 0;
Text myText = null;
whlie(myRecordReader.nextKeyValue() == true)
{
     if (count == 4)
     {
           myText = (Text) myRecordReader.getCurrentValue();
           break;
     }

     count++;
 }

 if (myText != null) // we didn't hit the end; we have a record
 {
     ... // create the tuple
     return myTuple;
 }
 else
     return null;
```

(*corrected my silly off-by-one mistake*)

Comment: I had read this before. The issue is that if you want to load only a random subset of the records in a file I didn't see a way to have the getNext method do that. Thats where I'm seeing if I should look in a method perhaps outside of the getNext method in which to implement the logic.

Comment: @Winter - erm, you'd just make it do that. If you wanted to use a method that returned one at time like `getNext()` you'd need to keep track of which ones you'd already returned, etc. If you want to return a sample set, just write a method that does that. Something like `public Tuple[] returnSampleSet()` (Or return a `List` of some type if you'd like).

Comment: See my edit above - that's how you could get every fifth one, one at a time, as a sample

Comment: I guess this is just where I'm new to Pig. If I used the returnSampleSet idea would it be able to extend the LoadFunc or would I have to load all the tuples first and then run them through the returnSampleSet function in a separate call of my Pig Script?

Comment: ok, i see what your saying. thanks for the code comment - that helped alot.

Comment: To return a whole set you would need to advance the RecordReader all the way from start to finish, extracting only the records you wanted to return.